# Calling encapsulated action creators in containing reducers

Tags: encapsulation, redux

I've got an encapsulated component with it's own reducer(s) and actions creators (all pure + synchronous). In the containing reducer, I require the component to get its reducer to handle the encapsulated state.

Normally, the component passes it's own actions up to the parent, and the parent dispatches a new action which gets get handled by sending the component action to its own reducer to handle that bit of state.

If I want to have external (to the component) actions affect the component state, is it reasonable to require and call the component's pure action creator(s) in the containing reducer, to then pass to the component's reducer? These actions are not getting dispatched, just created and passed directly to an appropriate reducer.

### Edit 2016-03-21:

Looking at this again, I think this question is too opinion-based to have a single useful answer; at least until the Redux docs themselves express an opinion. ZekeDroid's answer shows one good line of reasoning for arguing against, but I think it can be reasonably argued that using action creators in the reducer to pass the correct action to a child reducer is fine as well.

Comment: As a newb user, should this type of edit be added as an answer to flag "correct", such that the question is "closed"? Or should the question be flagged for a moderator to close?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost an opinion based answer so I'll give you my opinion. It's perfectly reasonable to call actions of other components that are not entirely related since having redux connected state means you expect that state to be shared by your application. Because of that, I think it ok to dispatch any action that affects state.

For example, a component which fetches async data may fire an action to disable a button somewhere outside its component. In that case you'd be dispatching an action of this other component (the button) which is perfectly reasonable (and easy to debug with something like redux dev tools!)

EDIT:

I tried to suggest how to "have external (to the component) actions affect the component state". To answer your question about calling action creators from a reducer, I think that from an abstract point of view this would be an anti-pattern as you are creating a loop in the state transition logic:

```
view => action => reducer => store => view
```

If you were to call the actions from the reducer, although you're not dispatching it, you're still attempting to use logic that should be used solely by views and other action creators in the reducers. A use case would be useful in this case so that we can provide an alternative solution without having to break the redux pattern.

Comment: It is a question begging an opinionated answer, but I think you answered a different question. My question is about calling action creators inside a reducer, not dispatching actions from other components. I'm not downvoting as an answer yet, in case I misunderstood. If it is unclear in the question, could you suggest some improvements?

Comment: Oooh I misunderstood then. Maybe the better question would be just that then: "Can I call an action creator from a reducer?". Let me edit and answer.

Comment: Looking at the question again, coupled with your answer(s), I think that it's probably too opinion-based to have a good SO-style answer; at least until the Redux docs themselves express an opinion on it. Thanks for trying!